# How do I display the data from a JTextField into a JTextArea?

Tags: java, events, actionlistener, settext

How do I display the data from a `JTextField` into a `JTextArea`?

I'm trying to take input from four `JTextField` and show them in a `JTextArea` when a button is clicked.  I have the `ActionListener` working. I am just unsure how to get the input to the `JTextArea`.

My `JTextArea` is called 'ShowActions'.  And I am getting some lines of code appearing in the `JTextArea`. But they are not the inputs I desired so bad.....

Can someone please point me in the right direction please?

```
private JPanel JPanel1 (){

JP1 = new JPanel();

//Style JP1
JP1.setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 2));
JP1.setBackground(Color.RED);
JP1.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

//Make bits and name them       
heading1 = new JLabel ("Add Landlord");
Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC + Font.BOLD, 28);
heading1.setFont(font);
spacer1 = new JLabel ("           ");
LLNameT = new JLabel ("Enter Landlord name");
LLName = new JTextField(30);
LLAddressT = new JLabel ("Enter Landlord Address ");
LLAddress = new JTextField(40);
LLPhoneT = new JLabel ("Enter Landlod Phone No.");
LLPhone = new JTextField(10);
LLbankDeetsT = new JLabel ("Enter Landlod Bank details");
LLbankDeets = new JTextField(10);
sub1 = new JButton("Submit"); 

//Add bits to panel 
JP1.add(heading1);
JP1.add(spacer1);
JP1.add(LLNameT); 
JP1.add(LLName);
JP1.add(LLAddressT);
JP1.add(LLAddress); 
JP1.add(LLPhoneT);
JP1.add(LLPhone); 
JP1.add(LLbankDeetsT );
JP1.add(LLbankDeets); 
JP1.add(sub1);

//Set Action Listener
event1  JP1sub1 = new event1();
sub1.addActionListener(JP1sub1);

return(JP1);
}   

//Activate ActionListener
public class event1 implements ActionListener{

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent JP1sub1){

     ShowActions.setText(LLName + "\n" + LLAddress + "\n" + LLPhone + "\n" + LLbankDeets);
}
```

}

Comment: JTextField.getText()???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close you need to do one more thing and that is getting the tekst from the labels and textfield by calling `getText()`.

```
 public class event1 implements ActionListener{

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent JP1sub1){
         ShowActions.setText(LLName.getText() + "\n" + LLAddress.getText() + "\n" + LLPhone.getText() + "\n" + LLbankDeets.getText());
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No problem you were indeed very close :)